# PHP / JSON parameters on url

Tags: php, json

I have created a php file which connects to the database, gets the data from table and shows it in json format.

The file in called index.php.

To view the json I just go to the file in the browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1/json/index.php and it displays:

{"title":[{"id":"1","title":"Title1","desc":"Description1"},{"id":"2","title":"Title2","desc":"Description2"}]}
```

What I need to do is to be able to filter this by adding parameters like:

```
For example: http://127.0.0.1/json/index.php?id=1 to just show the data with an id of 1 but it still shows all the data.
```

Here is the php code:

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select mydb");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
 $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows['title'][] = $r;
   }

 print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

What I'm I doing wrong here or missing?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $hostname = "localhost"; 

    //connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    $selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbhandle)
    or die("Could not select mydb");

    $id = 0;
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){ $id = (int)$_GET['id']; }

    if(!$id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `contacts`";
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `id`='".$id."'";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $rows['title'][] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: Getting error: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for ... Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\wamp\www\json\index.php on line 23..This is line 23:   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Comment: If works great when I add the ?id=1 at the end but doesn't display anything it I don't add the filter. I need it to just display add the data if I don't filter it.

Comment: and which query do I leave... $query = "SELECT * FROM `contacts`";
 or the other one?

Comment: leave them both, one is if the `$id` is set and the other for all. let me put the whole code

Comment: Works perfect but why do I get error:  Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\json\index.php on line 13 -- line 13 is: $id = (int)$_GET['id'];

Comment: Try the last piece of code I have in my answer, it should work now. Your getting that error because you have strict error reporting on. So you have to check if the index is set first using isset().

Answer (score 1):

Change following

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts");
```

to

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM contacts';

if(is_numeric($id))
    $query .= ' WHERE id = ' . $id;

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but I get an error if I don't do the filtering. And I need the filtering to be optional

Answer (score 1):

For one you have to add WHERE to your SQL statement....

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `id` = $id
```

Where you see `id` this should be the name of the id column in your table whatever that may be. But your also going to have to sanitize the input first...

```
if(!is_numeric($_GET['id']))
    exit; // if not a number then exit

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); // escape the input
```

Of course this is the most basic error checking. You could expound upon it. So your code would look more like this...

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select mydb");

if(!is_numeric($_GET['id']) || !$_GET['id'])
    exit; // if not an integer or id not set then exit

$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']); // escape the input

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = $id");
 $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows['title'][] = $r;
   }

 print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

And you really shouldn't use root to connect to the database in your web app. And also Mihai is right, you should use PDO instead, but it's not really necessary for such a simple app.

**Edit**
But the above code will require an `id` input. If you want to still be able to get the entire list if no `id` is provided it would look like this...

```
<?php

$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db("mydb",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select mydb");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contacts`";

if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
    // if id is set then add the WHERE statement
    if(!is_numeric($_GET['id']))
        die('id must be an integer');  // if id is not an integer then exit
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['id']); // escape the input
    $sql .= " WHERE `id` = $id"; // append the WHERE statement to the sql
}


$result = mysql_query($sql);
 $rows = array();
   while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $rows['title'][] = $r;
   }

 print json_encode($rows);

?>
```

Comment: If I hard code the id in the sql query I'm forced to have it filtered. I need it to be optional, so I can display all or add the filter via url.

Comment: Getting error: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\json\index.php on line 16 and when I add ?id=1 the page is blank

Comment: You probably have strict error reporting on. Try the above code now.

Comment: Also had to use is_numeric() instead of is_int().

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `where` condition to your query.

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE id = $id");
```